# Change n value (replicate value) not complete in riak

Tags: linux, riak

I have a riak system, i try change replicate value, but not commplete.
I use command line to change:

```
curl -v -XPUT \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{"props":{"n_val":2}}' \
  http://<my-ip-riak>:8098/buckets/<my-bucket>/props
```

then, I put file into riak by s3cmd:

```
s3cmd put <my-file> s3://<my-bucket>
```

and i check size of riak:

```
du -sh /var/lib/riak/
```

I see, it replicate 3, it not change replicate value.
Any help?

Cheers,

Nghiep

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `s3cmd`, you are using Riak CS, not Riak.  When you create a bucket using s3cmd, Riak CS creates 2 buckets: one to store manifests records and one to store data blocks.  Both bucket names are based on an md5 hash of the bucket name, using the [`riak_cs_utils:to_bucket_name/2`](https://github.com/basho/riak_cs/blob/develop/src/riak_cs_utils.erl#L493-L502) function.  Since the bucket name is binary, even if you correctly predict the name, you will not be able to send it in a URL to be able to change its properties.

You might be able to change the properties for a single bucket from an attach console or via protocol buffers, but I have never attempted this.

You should be able to change the default bucket properties in your app.config or riak.conf file so that all buckets use n_val=2.